# Selenium Java - entire class fail but individual testcase pass

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

```
public class testClassName(){
  @BeforeClass
  public void setup(){}

  @AfterClass
  public void cleanup(){}

  @test
  @step(value = 1)
  public void testcase1() throws exception{
  }

  @test
  @step(value = 2)
  public void testcase2() throws exception{}

  @test
  @step(value = 3)
  public void testcase3() throws exception{}

}
```

My Selenium test have the above format and everytime when I run the individual testcases, they all pass. However, when I run the entire class, the first testcase pass and the other two testcases fail.

For each testcase, it starts with open the same url page and click on a new button. However, when I run the entire class, the execution stops at the second testcase and complains that it cannot find the new button. Can anyone help me with this? The new button xpath and the url xpath are shared variables.

Answer (score 0):

Check the state of the browser window when the first test has passed. I guess that you forget to create appropriate after method and restore app state for the next tests. Real code example can be useful to understand what goes wrong.